# French accented characters decode for SQL matching

Tags: php, mysql, diacritics

I'm having a problem with matching against french accented characters (note that other different characters such as chinese, japanese will also be used).

I've ran across an error when I input a french street name that will check the database and I had an error:

```
Incorrect string value: '\xE2teau' for column 'street_name' at row 1
```

For this character in this name:

```
Le Château
```

I've changed my column to `utf8_general_ci` and it still throws me that error. How can you "decode" them to match against a column?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you actually sending UTF-8 data, or are you sending Latin-1 encoded data? MySQL may be choking on `âte` because `â` is being transmitted as the byte `E2` and it expects a byte with a suitable value to come next, but sees the `74` for `t` instead. Thus the string is not valid UTF-8.

Try using `utf8_encode()` on the string value before creating the query?